# LLVM update issue

Tags: c, clang, llvm

I am having issues getting my LLVM up to date, but I am running into the same issue. I am building a project in C that requires me to use LLVM tools. Some of tools weren't properly work, but I figured out what was the issue and it was that my LLVM library wasn't updated. Now comes the weird thing when I look at my LLVM directory `opt/homebrew/Cellar/llvm` I only have a single folder called `16.0.4` meaning it is up to date, but when I run `llvm-config --version`
I get `11.0.0`.

I am using MacOs with M1 chip. I have tried to reinstall the LLVM package several times, but I get the same result back that my directory states that it is up to date, but `llvm-config --version` tells me it isn't. I also tried to delete the directory and with bins fully and reinstall it but no change. I just need help figuring out my issue where I want to use the latest version of LLVM